# Time out error in deploying the process on weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

While deploying the BPEL process in Weblogic 10.3.4, following Exception comes on soa server console. I am sure this is not related to my application, but due to this I am not able to deploy the process on server, it lead with connection time out. I increased my connection time out also to 480.

Exception:

```
<Jun 8, 2011 10:15:37 PM SGT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for
queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "634" seconds working on the reques
t "weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@22ea883[
POST /soa-infra/deployer HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers, deflate, gzip, compress
User-Agent: Oracle HTTPClient Version 10h
Cookie2: $Version="1"
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, compress, x-compress
ECID-Context:
Authorization: Basic d2VibG9naWM6d2VibG9naWMx
Cookie: JSESSIONID=JB0KNvdct5X1X5z02FhLDm8jVWjdvXB0chchkQhXpzQFGb9JlF8L!-186412258
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 14824044

]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
Thread-16 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, in
 native, suspended, priority=1, DAEMON> {
    jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(SocketNativeIO.java:???)
    jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:24)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:???)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:107)
    oracle.net.nt.MetricsEnabledInputStream.read(TcpNTAdapter.java:707)
    oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:243)
    oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:309)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:254)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:187)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:1
22)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:77)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1172)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1153)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:303)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:181)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:382)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:70)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1017)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1330)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3722)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3869)
    ^-- Holding lock: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@d2596e[thin lock]
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.j
ava:1508)
    weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:160)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.platform.OracleDB.insertStreamedContent(OracleDB.java:890)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.DBStreamedContentHelper.insertContent(DBStreamedContentHelper
.java:73)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseReposAccess.saveStreamedDocument(BaseReposAccess.java:173
0)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseReposAccess.saveStreamedDocument(BaseReposAccess.java:161
5)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseDBMSConnection.saveDocumentWithComment(BaseDBMSConnection
.java:1811)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseDBMSConnection.saveDocument(BaseDBMSConnection.java:1698)

    oracle.mds.persistence.DelegatingMetadataStoreConnection.saveDocument(DelegatingMetadataStoreCon
nection.java:501)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.BufferedMSConnection.saveDocument(BufferedMSConnection.java:545)

    oracle.mds.persistence.PTransaction.saveStoreDocument(PTransaction.java:1314)
    oracle.mds.persistence.PTransaction.saveDocument(PTransaction.java:824)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.PersistenceUtils.createOrSaveDocument(PersistenceUtils.java:448)

    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferDocument(InternalMDSTransfer.java:3032)

    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferTransferUnit(InternalMDSTransfer.java:2
897)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferTransferUnitList(InternalMDSTransfer.ja
va:2828)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.execute(InternalMDSTransfer.java:1341)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.execute(InternalMDSTransfer.java:1263)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transfer(InternalMDSTransfer.java:426)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.MDSManager.transferCompositeData(MDSManager.ja
va:401)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deploySARs(BaseDeployProce
ssor.java:116)
    ^-- Holding lock: java.lang.Object@6253346[thin lock]
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.j
ava:122)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.j
ava:107)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeploy(DeployProcessor.java:
96)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.process(DeployProcessor.java:6
8)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPostInsideLoggingSe
ssion(CompositeDeployerServlet.java:130)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPost(CompositeDeplo
yerServlet.java:109)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:700)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:815)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:22
4)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:108)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:206)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:299)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:405)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:98)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:70)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:299)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:405)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:98)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:70)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:86)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletCont
ext.java:3687)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.
java:3681)
    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:308)
    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:116)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2213)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2135)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1420)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:168)
}

>
<Jun 8, 2011 10:15:37 PM SGT> <Notice> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320068> <Watch 'StuckThread' with severity
 'Notice' on server 'soa_server1' has triggered at Jun 8, 2011 10:15:37 PM SGT. Notification details
:
WatchRuleType: Log
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-000337') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000337'))
WatchData: DATE = Jun 8, 2011 10:15:37 PM SGT SERVER = soa_server1 MESSAGE = [STUCK] ExecuteThread:
'0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "634" seconds working on th
e request "weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@22ea883[
POST /soa-infra/deployer HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers, deflate, gzip, compress
User-Agent: Oracle HTTPClient Version 10h
Cookie2: $Version="1"
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, compress, x-compress
ECID-Context:
Authorization: Basic d2VibG9naWM6d2VibG9naWMx
Cookie: JSESSIONID=JB0KNvdct5X1X5z02FhLDm8jVWjdvXB0chchkQhXpzQFGb9JlF8L!-186412258
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 14824044

]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
Thread-16 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, in
 native, suspended, priority=1, DAEMON> {
    jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(SocketNativeIO.java:???)
    jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:24)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:???)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:107)
    oracle.net.nt.MetricsEnabledInputStream.read(TcpNTAdapter.java:707)
    oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:243)
    oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:309)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:254)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:187)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:1
22)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:77)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1172)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1153)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:303)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:181)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:382)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:70)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1017)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1330)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3722)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3869)
    ^-- Holding lock: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@d2596e[thin lock]
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.j
ava:1508)
    weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:160)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.platform.OracleDB.insertStreamedContent(OracleDB.java:890)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.DBStreamedContentHelper.insertContent(DBStreamedContentHelper
.java:73)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseReposAccess.saveStreamedDocument(BaseReposAccess.java:173
0)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseReposAccess.saveStreamedDocument(BaseReposAccess.java:161
5)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseDBMSConnection.saveDocumentWithComment(BaseDBMSConnection
.java:1811)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseDBMSConnection.saveDocument(BaseDBMSConnection.java:1698)

    oracle.mds.persistence.DelegatingMetadataStoreConnection.saveDocument(DelegatingMetadataStoreCon
nection.java:501)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.BufferedMSConnection.saveDocument(BufferedMSConnection.java:545)

    oracle.mds.persistence.PTransaction.saveStoreDocument(PTransaction.java:1314)
    oracle.mds.persistence.PTransaction.saveDocument(PTransaction.java:824)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.PersistenceUtils.createOrSaveDocument(PersistenceUtils.java:448)

    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferDocument(InternalMDSTransfer.java:3032)

    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferTransferUnit(InternalMDSTransfer.java:2
897)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferTransferUnitList(InternalMDSTransfer.ja
va:2828)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.execute(InternalMDSTransfer.java:1341)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.execute(InternalMDSTransfer.java:1263)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transfer(InternalMDSTransfer.java:426)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.MDSManager.transferCompositeData(MDSManager.ja
va:401)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deploySARs(BaseDeployProce
ssor.java:116)
    ^-- Holding lock: java.lang.Object@6253346[thin lock]
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.j
ava:122)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.j
ava:107)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeploy(DeployProcessor.java:
96)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.process(DeployProcessor.java:6
8)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPostInsideLoggingSe
ssion(CompositeDeployerServlet.java:130)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPost(CompositeDeplo
yerServlet.java:109)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:700)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:815)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:22
4)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:108)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:206)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:299)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:405)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:98)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:70)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:299)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:405)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:98)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:70)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:86)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletCont
ext.java:3687)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.
java:3681)
    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:308)
    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:116)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2213)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2135)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1420)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:168)
}

 SUBSYSTEM = WebLogicServer USERID = <WLS Kernel> SEVERITY = Error THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread:
'5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' MSGID = BEA-000337 MACHINE = urasvr140 TXID =
  CONTEXTID = da07387a98ce3972:315f7e44:1306f8b304d:-8000-0000000000000338 TIMESTAMP = 1307542537412

WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset
WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 600000
>
<Jun 8, 2011 10:15:39 PM SGT> <Alert> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320016> <Creating diagnostic image in d:\or
acle\middleware\user_projects\domains\test_domain\servers\soa_server1\adr\diag\ofm\test_domain\soa_s
erver1\incident\incdir_54 with a lockout minute period of 1.>
<Jun 8, 2011 10:16:37 PM SGT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for
queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "694" seconds working on the reques
t "weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@22ea883[
POST /soa-infra/deployer HTTP/1.1
Connection: TE
TE: trailers, deflate, gzip, compress
User-Agent: Oracle HTTPClient Version 10h
Cookie2: $Version="1"
Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, compress, x-compress
ECID-Context:
Authorization: Basic d2VibG9naWM6d2VibG9naWMx
Cookie: JSESSIONID=JB0KNvdct5X1X5z02FhLDm8jVWjdvXB0chchkQhXpzQFGb9JlF8L!-186412258
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 14824044

]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
Thread-16 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, in
 native, suspended, priority=1, DAEMON> {
    jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(SocketNativeIO.java:???)
    jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:24)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:???)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:107)
    oracle.net.nt.MetricsEnabledInputStream.read(TcpNTAdapter.java:707)
    oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:243)
    oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:309)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:254)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:187)
    oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:1
22)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:77)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1172)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1153)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:303)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:181)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:382)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:70)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1017)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1330)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3722)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3869)
    ^-- Holding lock: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@d2596e[thin lock]
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.j
ava:1508)
    weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:160)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.platform.OracleDB.insertStreamedContent(OracleDB.java:890)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.DBStreamedContentHelper.insertContent(DBStreamedContentHelper
.java:73)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseReposAccess.saveStreamedDocument(BaseReposAccess.java:173
0)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseReposAccess.saveStreamedDocument(BaseReposAccess.java:161
5)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseDBMSConnection.saveDocumentWithComment(BaseDBMSConnection
.java:1811)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.db.BaseDBMSConnection.saveDocument(BaseDBMSConnection.java:1698)

    oracle.mds.persistence.DelegatingMetadataStoreConnection.saveDocument(DelegatingMetadataStoreCon
nection.java:501)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.BufferedMSConnection.saveDocument(BufferedMSConnection.java:545)

    oracle.mds.persistence.PTransaction.saveStoreDocument(PTransaction.java:1314)
    oracle.mds.persistence.PTransaction.saveDocument(PTransaction.java:824)
    oracle.mds.internal.persistence.PersistenceUtils.createOrSaveDocument(PersistenceUtils.java:448)

    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferDocument(InternalMDSTransfer.java:3032)

    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferTransferUnit(InternalMDSTransfer.java:2
897)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transferTransferUnitList(InternalMDSTransfer.ja
va:2828)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.execute(InternalMDSTransfer.java:1341)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.execute(InternalMDSTransfer.java:1263)
    oracle.mds.internal.transfer.InternalMDSTransfer.transfer(InternalMDSTransfer.java:426)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.MDSManager.transferCompositeData(MDSManager.ja
va:401)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.BaseDeployProcessor.deploySARs(BaseDeployProce
ssor.java:116)
    ^-- Holding lock: java.lang.Object@6253346[thin lock]
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.j
ava:122)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeployWork(DeployProcessor.j
ava:107)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.doDeploy(DeployProcessor.java:
96)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.DeployProcessor.process(DeployProcessor.java:6
8)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPostInsideLoggingSe
ssion(CompositeDeployerServlet.java:130)
    oracle.integration.platform.blocks.deploy.servlet.CompositeDeployerServlet.doPost(CompositeDeplo
yerServlet.java:109)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:700)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:815)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:22
4)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:108)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:206)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:299)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:405)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:98)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:70)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:299)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:405)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:98)
    oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:70)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:86)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletCont
ext.java:3687)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.
java:3681)
    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:308)
    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:116)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2213)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2135)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1420)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:168)
}

>
```

Please tell me what this is related to and how can I overcome this problem.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What the message tells you is that you have a stuck thread while deploying your BPEL app. The specific URL it is working on is

```
/soa-infra/deployer
```

Weblogic does NOT kill stuck threads after the `StuckThreadMaxTime`. It cannot do so, the message is only a status info so that you (i.e. admin) is aware that the thread has crossed 600 sec = 10 min of time while trying to deploy.

This is a configurable value.

The timer starts when the thread begins processing the request within the server. The thread will not be killed but will actually go on processing until the operation is over.

Now there are some operative parts of the stacktrace that you should look at.

```
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:1
    22)
```

This indicates some operation with the database via the JDBC driver

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1330)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3722)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3869)
        ^-- Holding lock: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@d2596e[thin lock]
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.j
    ava:1508)
```

The `Holding lock` shows the point at which it is stuck - another thread is holding a lock to the JDBC connection

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
```

I have not used BPEL myself - but my guesstimate on this operation is that while deploying the app, it needs multiple connections to the database via the Connection Pool, and it seems to not get enough.

Have you configured some size for the pool and can you increase that?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning. I get the same message when executing services that may take a long to finish. It doesn't create any actual problem in execution though, so you could just ignore it.

If you want to get rid of the warning (i wouldn't suggest to do that) you can open your server console and change the configuration. Specifically, for Weblogic (11g?), you should navigate to Environment Collapse NodeEnvironment> servers> {your_server}> Configuration> Overload> Max Stuck Thread Time and change from "600" to whatever you think.
PS. I dont know to tell you if that change cause any problem of your server's execution! You should look after for any.